# iText7 failed to generate PDF

Tags: java, itext7

Use iText7 to generate PDF. When adding table elements, the program will throw an exception if the cell content of the table is too long.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEhGw.png)

Using iText7-core version 7.1.15.How do I need to adjust the program control cells?

Comment: *"When adding table elements, the program will throw an exception if the cell content of the table is too long."* - The exception looks more like an issue with a font used.